# Is a created element, considered as a child?

Tags: javascript, parent-child

In javascript if you have this by example:
`const a = document.createElement("img");`
`a.src = "test.png";`
`document.getElementById("parent").appendChild(a);`

Will this give true? -> `document.getElementById("parent").hasChildNodes();`

Comment: Why do you ask when you can actually try it? Turn the code in your question into a runnable snippet, run it, and ... remove the question, as it will be answered.

Comment: @trincot he is new on StackOverflow, and you know what is the first task on the stack overflow, ask a question. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const a = document.createElement("img");
a.src = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b4185aac47f6262b40dc8f11535a32c0?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG"; 
document.getElementById("parent").appendChild(a);
console.log(document.getElementById("parent").hasChildNodes());
```

```html
<div id="parent"></div>
```